# query for comparing two tables if they are identical says the tables are the same when they aren't

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

tableA has columns `a,b,c,d,e,f,g`

tableB has columns `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,i,j,k,l,m,n,o`

i want to see if the data from tableA for columns a to g is identical to the data from the tableB columns a to g. I am using this query

```
select a,b,c,d,e,f,g from tableA
union
select a,b,c,d,e,f,g from tableB
except 
select a,b,c,d,e,f,g from tableA
intersect 
select a,b,c,d,e,f,g from tableB
```

I should mention that `'a'` is a name like `abc_1c, abc_5c, cfg_10x` and so on and `'b'` is a `date`.

If the tables are identical on those columns they shouldn't return anything. The only problem is that the tableA has 180576 rows and tableB has 181404 rows. Where i am making a mistake and how can I get what I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get data that are different between tables like `XOR`

**[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ded13/1/0)**

```
(select a,b,c,d,e,f,g, 'tableA' AS [source] from tableA
except
select a,b,c,d,e,f,g, 'tableA' from tableB)
union all
(select a,b,c,d,e,f,g, 'tableB' AS [source] from tableB
except
select a,b,c,d,e,f,g, 'tableB' from tableA);
```

or:

```
(select a,b,c,d,e,f,g from tableA
UNION ALL
select a,b,c,d,e,f,g from tableB)
EXCEPT
(select a,b,c,d,e,f,g from tableB
INTERSECT
select a,b,c,d,e,f,g from tableA);
```

So if no row returned the tables are identical.

**EDIT:**

You probably have duplicates in one of tables, try:

```
SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g, COUNT(*)
FROM tableB    /* or tableA */
GROUP BY a,b,c,d,e,f,g
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Enhanced version which will detect duplicates:

**[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b2799/4)**

```
(SELECT
   a,b,c,d,e,f,g,
   [source] = 'tableA',
   [rn] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a,b,c,d,e,f,g ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
FROM tableA
EXCEPT
SELECT
   a,b,c,d,e,f,g,
   [source] = 'tableA',
   [rn] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a,b,c,d,e,f,g ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
FROM tableB)
UNION ALL
(SELECT
   a,b,c,d,e,f,g,
   [source] = 'tableB',
   [rn] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a,b,c,d,e,f,g ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
FROM tableB
EXCEPT
SELECT
   a,b,c,d,e,f,g,
   [source] = 'tableB',
   [rn] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a,b,c,d,e,f,g ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
FROM tableA)
```

Comment: first of all thank you. Tried both of your queries. The first one gives me syntax errors. The second one works but returns 0 rows and as I said they have different numbers of rows. What now?

Comment: If you use `DATETIME`, make sure the time part is the same, maybe they vary with seconds/miliseconds, if so convert to full days

Comment: @viorelmunteanu There is no place for syntax error, could you paste error message for first?

Comment: the date column is the same in both of them. At first i had one table, tableA. tableB was created based on tableA and a to g should be identical and the rest of them (h to o) are just calculations based on what i had inserted into a new table. I don't know why i am having more lines and how can I find the differences.

Comment: @viorelmunteanu See fiddle, it will return you differences for both tables with info from which table it comes. It has to work, because it is Math

Comment: the error i get is at `(select` the very first line

Comment: Add `;` before `(` and in the end, if fiddle it works perfectly fine, I can't reproduce your error

Comment: @viorelmunteanu I know why second return you 0 rows, because you have duplicated rows in second table. See my updated answer and except get rid off duplicates

Answer (score 1):

assuming no relevant column can be null, i'd do it a bit differently:

```
select 'a', a.a,a.b,a.c,a.d,a.e,a.f,a.g 
     , 'b', b.a,b.b,b.c,b.d,b.e,b.f,b.g 
from      tableA a
full join tableB b
     on  a.a = a.b
     and a.b = b.b
     and a.c = b.c
     and a.d = b.d
     and a.e = b.f
     and a.g = b.g
where a.a is null 
   or b.a is null
```

if any column can be null, the query will be a bit more complicated:

`coalesce(null,1) = isnull(null,1)` is the same

you have to choose an alternative to null which can't be in that column

if any numeric col can't be below 0, you can write `coalesce(null,-1)`

if you you choose an string, you'll have to cast the number first

```
select a = coalesce(a.a,b.a)    
     , b = coalesce(a.b,b.b)
     , c = coalesce(a.c,b.c)
     , 'a', a.a,a.b,a.c
     , 'b', b.a,b.b,b.c
from      tableA a
full join tableB b
     on  a.a = b.a
     and coalesce(upper(a.b),'null') = coalesce(upper(b.b),'null')
     and coalesce(      a.c , -1   ) = coalesce(      b.c , -1   )
where a.a is null 
   or b.a is null
order by coalesce(a.a,b.a)
       , coalesce(a.b,b.b)
       , coalesce(a.c,b.c)
```

Comment: what if i have some null values in a column. Not the entire column. Let's say 2000 from 180 k ? (becasue i do)

Comment: @viorelmunteanu added a version with nulls